# Project Euler 104: Need help in understanding the solution

Tags: python, math

Project Euler Q104 (https://projecteuler.net/problem=104) is as such:

> The Fibonacci sequence is defined by the recurrence relation:
>
> Fn = Fn−1 + Fn−2, where F1 = 1 and F2 = 1. It turns out that F541,
>   which contains 113 digits, is the first Fibonacci number for which the
>   last nine digits are 1-9 pandigital (contain all the digits 1 to 9,
>   but not necessarily in order). And F2749, which contains 575 digits,
>   is the first Fibonacci number for which the first nine digits are 1-9
>   pandigital.
>
> Given that Fk is the first Fibonacci number for which the first nine
>   digits AND the last nine digits are 1-9 pandigital, find k.

And I wrote this simple code in Python:

```
def fibGen():
    a,b = 1,1
    while True:
        a,b = b,a+b
        yield a

k = 0
fibG = fibGen()
while True:
    k += 1
    x = str(fibG.next())
    if (set(x[-9:]) == set("123456789")):
        print x #debugging print statement
        if(set(x[:9]) == set("123456789")):
            break

print k
```

However, it was taking well.. forever.

After leaving it running for 30 mins, puzzled, I gave up and checked the solution.

I came across this code in C#:

```
long fn2 = 1;
long fn1 = 1;
long fn;

long tailcut = 1000000000;

int n = 2;
bool found = false;

while (!found) {
    n++;
    fn = (fn1 + fn2) % tailcut;
    fn2 = fn1;
    fn1 = fn;

    if (IsPandigital(fn)) {
        double t = (n * 0.20898764024997873 - 0.3494850021680094);
        if (IsPandigital((long)Math.Pow(10, t - (long)t + 8)))
            found = true;
    }
}
```

Which.. I could barely understand. I tried it out in VS, got the correct answer and checked the thread for help.

I found these two, similar looking answers in Python then.

One here, http://blog.dreamshire.com/project-euler-104-solution/

And one from the thread:

```
from math import sqrt

def isPandigital(s):
    return set(s) == set('123456789')

rt5=sqrt(5)
def check_first_digits(n):
    def mypow( x, n ):
        res=1.0
        for i in xrange(n):
            res *= x
            # truncation to avoid overflow:
            if res>1E20: res*=1E-10
        return res
    # this is an approximation for large n:
    F = mypow( (1+rt5)/2, n )/rt5
    s = '%f' % F
    if isPandigital(s[:9]):
        print n
        return True

a, b, n = 1, 1, 1
while True:
    if isPandigital( str(a)[-9:] ):
        print a
        # Only when last digits are
        # pandigital check the first digits:
        if check_first_digits(n):
            break
    a, b = b, a+b
    b=b%1000000000
    n += 1

print n
```

These worked pretty fast, under 1 minute!
I really need help understanding these solutions. I don't really know the meaning or the reason behind using stuff like log. And though I could easily do the first 30 questions, I cannot understand these tougher ones.

How is the best way to solve this question and how these solutions are implementing it?

Comment: It's not important to understand the particular programs you found, but it is important to understand the ideas that might come into play. I have a couple of ideas. One is that the least-significant (last) digits are always constructed from the least-significant digits of the preceding numbers, right? So you can you modular arithmetic (i.e. `%` in Python) to calculate them -- that should be faster. The other is that even a very inaccurate approximation will give the most-significant (first) digits. Fibonacci numbers are exactly a linear combination of powers of the roots of `x^2 - x - 1 = 0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two solutions work on the bases that as fibonacci numbers get bigger, the ratio between two consecutive terms gets closer to a number known as the [Golden Ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), `(1+sqrt(5))/2`, roughly 1.618.  If you have one (large) fibonacci number, you can easily calculate the next, just by multiplying it by that number.

We know from the question that only large fibonacci numbers are going to satisfy the conditions, so we can use that to quickly calculate the parts of the sequence we're interested in.

In your implementation, to calculate `fib(n)`, you need to calculate `fib(n-1)`, which needs to calculate `fib(n-2)` , which needs to calculate `fib(n-3)` etc, *and* it needs to calculate `fib(n-2)`, which calculates `fib(n-3)` etc.  That's a huge number of function calls when n is big.  Having a single calculation to know what number comes next is a huge speed increase.  A computer scientist would call the first method O(n^2)*: to calculate `fib(n)`, you need n^2 sub calculations.  Using the golden mean, the fibonacci sequence becomes (approximately, but close enouigh for what we need):

```
(using phi = (1+sqrt(5))/2)

1
1*phi
1*phi*phi = pow(phi, 2)
1*phi*phi*phi = pow(phi, 3)
...
1*phi*...*phi = pow(phi, n)
 \  n times /
```

So, you can do an O(1) calculation: `fib(n): return round(pow(golden_ratio, n)/(5**0.5))`

Next, there's a couple of simplifications that let you use smaller numbers.

If I'm concerned about the last nine digits of a number, what happens further up isn't all that important, so I can throw anything after the 9th digit from the right away.  That's what `b=b%1000000000` or `fn = (fn1 + fn2) % tailcut;` are doing.  `%` is the [modulus operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation), which says, if I divide the left number by the right, what's the remainder?

It's easiest to explain with equivalent code:

```
def mod(a,b):
    while a > b:
        a -= b
    return a
```

So, there's a quick addition loop that adds together the last nine digits of fibonacci numbers, waiting for them to be pandigital.  If it is, it calculates the whole value of the fibonacci number, and check the first nine digits.

Let me know if I need to cover anything in more detail.

* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Btw, one thing.. Won't throwing away everything after the 10th digit affect the fib sequence's next terms?

Comment: And by everything after the 10th digit, you meant everything before the 10th digit right? Like if the number is 51621..796978839725641, you throw away everything except 839725641?

Comment: Not in the digits we care about. You'll notice we recalculate the whole number if we find one we're interested in. And yes, I meant before, I'm used to counting bits, which works backwards to everything else: the least significant bit is bit 0.

Comment: I can't find where he's recalculating the whole number.. :/

Comment: As in, I can find it, but I don't see how it is affecting the original sequence.

Comment: To better frame my question, lets say Ive got 2 large numbers, that I've truncated, and got only the last 9 digits. I add them up, to get the next turn of the fib sequence. So the last 9 digits of the term will still be the same, even if I had not thrown away everything besides the last 9 digits in the prev 2 terms?

Comment: You add them up to get *the last nine digits* of the next fibonacci number.  Yes, consider 1234 + 5678 = 6912 , and 34 and 78 = 112: if you only look at the last two digits, the answers are identical.  The hundreds digit is different, but we don't care about that.  That's what we're doing here, except with much bigger numbers, and the last nine digits.

Comment: Yes, and now I remember there was one Euler question based on this, but with Python's easy long integers and stuff, I didn't think of adding only the first digits, and truncating the rest. https://projecteuler.net/problem=13 Thanks a lot though, I got it now :)

Comment: Incidentally, the tricks used get around the fact that `pow(phi, n)` isn't exact to single unit digits: we don't need to care how accurate the least significant digits are, because we've already checked them using a calculation we know produces their exact value.

Comment: btw.. won't it be def fib(n): return round(pow(golden_ratio, n)/(5**0.5)) ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm misremembering the equation